# In Stimulsoft Report Designer , How To Invisible an Object , When Save or Print The Report?

Tags: stimulsoft

I Designed a Report in Stimul Report  , and I Use Image Box as Icon for Run Some Function,... 
**{[This Is a Screen Shot Of My Reports.](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-12/14139879395465787928.png)}**
  I Want **Don't Display These Icon** , When User Print Or Save The Report, Is It Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I define 2 Style for my Image Box , and change the style to transparent for printing.

Comment: Could you please describe your method more?

Comment: i forget details of my method , but i remeber that it's possible to define a style special for print.

Comment: Dear @EmadArmoun  , i forget my nethod because  i don't use stimul in my project , if you're still involved , i can install the stimul and check the report and share with you and others.

Comment: Dear @Moein, I'll be grateful If you do it.